# How to handle Spring Boot's redirection to /error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I've encountered the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902374/spring-boot-rest-service-exception-handling), using Spring Boot 1.3.0 and not having my controllers annotated with `@RestController`, just `@Path` and `@Service`. As the OP in that question says,

> this is, to me, anything but sensible

I also can't understand why would they have it redirect to /error. And it **is very likely that I'm missing something**, because I can only give back 404s or 200s to the client.

My problem is that his solution doesn't seem to work with 1.3.0, so I have the following request flow: let's say my code throws a `NullPointerException`. It'll be handled by one of my `ExceptionMapper`s

```
@Provider
public class GeneralExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GeneralExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
        LOGGER.error(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

And my code returns a 500, but instead of sending it back to the client, it tries to redirect it to /error. If I don't have another resource for that, it'll send back a 404.

```
2015-12-16 18:33:21.268  INFO 9708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter  : 1 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
1 > GET http://localhost:8080/nullpointerexception
1 > accept: */*
1 > host: localhost:8080
1 > user-agent: curl/7.45.0

2015-12-16 18:33:29.492  INFO 9708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter  : 1 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
1 < 500

2015-12-16 18:33:29.540  INFO 9708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter  : 2 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
2 > GET http://localhost:8080/error
2 > accept: */*
2 > host: localhost:8080
2 > user-agent: curl/7.45.0

2015-12-16 18:33:37.249  INFO 9708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter  : 2 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-1
2 < 404
```

And client's side (curl):

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/nullpointerexception
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1090 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying ::1...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1143 (connection #0)
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1240 (connection #0)
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x6000572d0; line 1258 (connection #0)
> GET /nullpointerexception HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x6000572d0; line 1337 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x6000572d0; line 1464 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x6000572d0; line 1474 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 17:33:37 GMT
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x6000572d0; line 1632 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

So it's always a 404. Unless I do have such an /error resource, then what? what am I supposed to return? All I have at that point is a GET request to /error. And I don't want those extra requests consuming resources and polluting my logs.

What am I missing? And if nothing, what should I do with my exception handling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the Jersey property [`ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR) to `true`.

> Whenever response status is `4xx` or `5xx` it is possible to choose between `sendError` or `setStatus` on container specific Response implementation. E.g. on servlet container Jersey can call `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(...)` or `HttpServletResponse.sendError(...)`.
>
> Calling `sendError(...)` method usually resets entity, response headers and provide error page for specified status code (e.g. servlet `error-page` configuration). However if you want to post-process response (e.g. by servlet filter) the only way to do it is calling `setStatus(...)` on container Response object.
>
> If property value is true the method `Response.setStatus(...)` is used over default `Response.sendError(...)`.
>
> Type of the property value is `boolean`. The default value is `false`.

You can set Jersey property simply by calling `property(key, value)` in your `ResourceConfig` subclass constructor.