# spring boot filter don't return right response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I'm developing a spring boot app and I'm following this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey),
it all works fine despite some adaptations required to make it work on spring boot but the problem is when I call:

```
requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
```

it returns "404 Not Found" instead of "401 Unauthorized", the method is called, it catches the exception but it return the wrong status.

Obs: If I remove the constraint of the filter it works normally.

the filter:

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Component
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

    if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
    }

    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

    try {

        validateToken(token);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
    }
}

private void validateToken(String token) throws Exception {
}
}
```

the resource :

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class Hello {

@Secured
@GET
@Path("/hello")
public String test() {
    return "Hello!";
}
@GET
@Path("/world")
public String world() {
    return "World!";
}
}
```

Comment: Try [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34321347/2587435)

Comment: Works like a charm thanks a lot, please make a proper reply so I can choose your answer.

Comment: Rather just close it as a dupe :-) Use case might not be the same, but the cause is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the Jersey API to build your RESTful interface. The 404 you are receiving relates to (I think) the `@Path` (Jersey) or `@RequestMapping` (spring).

If you post more code relating to the path of your API, then we can help further.

Thank you.

If you look to the top level path `@Path("/")`. You're adding another forward-slash so the uri will end up looking like:

`http://localhost.com//hello`
`http://localhost.com//world`

To fix this remove the forward-slash from the methods `@Path` annotation, and rebuild. This should result in API endpoints which look like

`http://localhost.com/hello`
`http://localhost.com/world`

Comment: that's not the problem, both endpoints are working, "world" method returns the string normally and hello get intercepted by the filter, the problem is that the filter doesn't return the right response, if I remove the if on the filter "hello" method work normally. (spring boot works with or without the extra "/", I just tested).

Comment: could you add the relevant filter code?

Comment: Is in the question already.

Comment: why should validate token throw an exception when nothing happens?

Comment: I was testing to see if this approach would work.