# spring boot override default REST exception handler

Tags: spring, rest, groovy, spring-boot

I am not able to override default spring boot error response in REST api. I have following code

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Controller
class ExceptionHandlerCtrl {

    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, reason="Invalid data")
    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessValidationException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<BusinessValidationErrorVO> handleBusinessValidationException(BusinessValidationException exception){
        BusinessValidationErrorVO vo = new BusinessValidationErrorVO()
        vo.errors = exception.validationException
        vo.msg = exception.message
        def result =  new ResponseEntity<>(vo, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        result

    }
```

Then in my REST api I am throwing this BusinessValidationException. This handler is called (I can see it in debugger) however I still got default spring boot REST error message. Is there a way to override and use default only as fallback? Spring Boot version 1.3.2 with groovy. Best Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `@ResponseStatus` from your method. It creates an undesirable side effect and you don't need it, since you are setting `HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` in your `ResponseEntity`.

From the [JavaDoc on `ResponseStatus`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html):

> Warning: when using this annotation on an exception class, or when setting the reason attribute of this annotation, the `HttpServletResponse.sendError` method will be used.
>
> With `HttpServletResponse.sendError`, the response is considered complete and should not be written to any further. Furthermore, **the Servlet container will typically write an HTML error page therefore making the use of a reason unsuitable for REST APIs. For such cases it is preferable to use a `ResponseEntity` as a return type and avoid the use of `@ResponseStatus` altogether.**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this question: [Spring Boot REST service exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902374/spring-boot-rest-service-exception-handling)

There you can find some examples that explain how to combine  ErrorController/ ControllerAdvice in order to catch any exception.

In particular check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28903217/379906

You should probably remove the annotation **@ResponseStatus** from the method handleBusinessValidationException.

Another way that you have to rewrite the default error message is using a controller with the annotation @RequestMapping("/error"). The controller must implement the **ErrorController** interface.

This is the error controller that I use in my app.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class RestErrorController implements ErrorController
{
    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Autowired
    public MatemoErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        Assert.notNull(errorAttributes, "ErrorAttributes must not be  null");
    this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
  }

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return "/error";
}

@RequestMapping
public Map<String, Object> error(HttpServletRequest aRequest) {

    return getErrorAttributes(aRequest, getTraceParameter(aRequest));
}

private boolean getTraceParameter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String parameter = request.getParameter("trace");
    if (parameter == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return !"false".equals(parameter.toLowerCase());
}

private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest  aRequest, boolean includeStackTrace)
{
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new  ServletRequestAttributes(aRequest);
    return errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes,  includeStackTrace);
}  }
```