# Handle REST Service in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have below code  use to `POST` JSON object to the following URL

```
        HttpEntity messageEntity = new HttpEntity(message, buildHttpHeaders(getTerminalId()));
        String theUrl = "http://123.433.234.12/receive";
        try {
               System.out.println("In try block");
               ResponseEntity<Dto> responseEntity= restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.POST, messageEntity, Dto.class);
          } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
              // get http status code
          }
```

If the URL is invalid or service unavailable, I want it throw error status code like 404 or 503. Unfortunatelly it will always stop at the `try` block..Is there a way to solve that ?

**Output**

```
In try block
```

**Edit**

```
 String theUrl = "http://123.433.234.12/receive" + transactionId; //invalid Id
   try {
          System.out.println("=========start=========");
          ResponseEntity<Dto> responseEntity= restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.POST, messageEntity, Dto.class);
          System.out.println("=========end=========");
       } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
          String a = ex.getStatusCode().toString();
          System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Output

```
=========start=========
2017-09-22 14:54:54 [xles-server-ThreadPool.PooledThread-0-running] ERROR c.r.abc.jpos.JposRequestListener - Error HttpStatusCode 500org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
```

It stop and not display `========end ========` or any status code in `catch` block

Valid url

```
   http://abc0/receive/hello
```

If I change to

```
 http://abc0/recei/hello
```

I will get `404` in catch block, it look fine. But when I change to another url that not exits,example

```
 http://123.433.234.12/receive
```

it is in try block .Why ????

Comment: If an exception is thrown, it will be in catch block... What another way are you asking??

Comment: You mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902374/spring-boot-rest-service-exception-handling/30193013#30193013)?

Comment: @MehrajMalik It in the try block

Comment: @soorapadman tried that too

Comment: @JohnJoe In the original question (non edited) you mentioned: "I want it throw error status code like 404 or 503". Answers were given keeping that in mind. Then you downvote the answer because you wanted to handle other error codes as well? You should have mentioned it clearly in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-), you should catch `RestClientException` instead of just `HttpStatusCodeException`.

If you want to throw exception in specific scenarios you can do it like this

```
    try {
        restTemplate.exchange(...);
    }
    catch (RestClientException e) {
        // implies error is related to i/o. 
        if (e instanceof ResourceAccessException) {
            // java.net.ConnectException will be wrapped in e with message "Connection timed out".
            if (e.contains(ConnectException.class)) {
                // handle connection timeout excp
            }
        } else if (e instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
            // Handle all HTTP 4xx error codes here;

        } else if (e instanceof HttpServerErrorException) {
            // Handle all HTTP 5xx error codes here
        }
    }
```

for `HttpClientErrorException` you can get error code from excption as shown below

```
HttpClientErrorException clientExcp = (HttpClientErrorException) e;
HttpStatus statusCode = clientExcp.getStatusCode();
```

like wise, you could get error code for `HttpServerErrorException`.

Comment: check the post again

Comment: @JohnJoe Very poor and confusing explanation of the problem you gave, recent edits made it clear what exactly you want. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the status code for server error ?

Comment: Yes, you can do something like

```HttpServerErrorException serverExcp = (HttpServerErrorException) e;
HttpStatus statusCode = serverExcp.getStatusCode();```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember `RestTemplate.exchange` method throws `RestClientException`. You have `HttpStatusCodeException` in your catch clause, which is only one of `RestClientException` subclasses.
The address you're trying to reach (`http://123.433.234.12/receive`) is not valid address, therefore you can't get ANY response from it (no 200s but no 500s or 400s too). Try to catch `RestClientException` and print its message to see what is going on. Then you can write some code to manage such situations.

Moreover if that does not work, try to go step by step and check wether `ResponseEntity` is null and what it has in its body. That's what I'm doing when I try to understand some method ;=)

Comment: I use `RestClientException` and it still stop at 

`=========start=========`

Comment: After few seconds I get `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://123.433.234.12/receive": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)`. Is there a way I can handle the exception ?