# how to catch exception in spring boot rest api

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, exception

i have a restcontroller with following Code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/student")
public void addTopic(@RequestBody Student student) {
    student.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(student.getPassword()));
    studentService.addStudent(student);
}
```

but if the json data doesn't match the Student object, or is wrong formatted an com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)) ist thrown.

what is the best practice to prevent that

Comment: "_what is the best practice to prevent that_" Send the correct JSON format.

Comment: yeah for my webapp thats true, but what about People using other tools and send wrong data. I want to check the data and send and send a Response if ist not correctly json formatted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot REST service exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902374/spring-boot-rest-service-exception-handling)

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I need to catch `JsonProcessingException` (which `JsonParseException` extends from) in the `@ExceptionHandler` rather than `JsonParseException`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class FeatureToggleControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(JsonProcessingException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<JSONAPIDocument> handleJsonParseException(JsonProcessingException ex) {
        final Error error = new Error();
        error.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        error.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString());
        error.setTitle(ex.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(JSONAPIDocument
                .createErrorDocument(Collections.singleton(error)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

Using `JsonParseException` in the above sample and nothing is caught, but using `JsonProcessingException` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring [ExceptionHandler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could specify an ExceptionHandler based on Exception types and also apply the error codes you want to use.

```
@ExceptionHandler(JsonParseException.class)
public JacksonExceptionHandler {
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleError(final Exception exception) {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    if (exception != null) {
        LOGGER.warn("Responding with status code {} and exception message {}", status, exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(), status);
    }
}
```

Furthermore you could make use of `javax.validation` to validate the entity you receive and then Spring Boot will do all the validation automagically. Just add `@Valid` to the body.